# Using equations with slicing through numpy arrays Pythopn

Tags: arrays, function, numpy, indexing, slice

I am trying to write an equation where it calculates the sum of the previous index and the current index and then divides it by the current index. So the equation (Current value+ previous value)/previous value) would output `(52599 + 52575)/52575` for the first two values (52599  52575) and then `(52575 + 52598)/52598` for the next two values (52575, 53598) and so on. I do not know how I can go about doing this.

```
Numbers = np.array([ 52599  52575  53598 336368 336875 337466 338292 356587 357474 357763 358491 358659 359041 360179 360286])
Equation = (Current value+ previous value)/previous value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```py
numbers = np.array([52599, 52575, 53598, 336368, 336875, 337466, 338292, 356587, 357474, 357763, 358491, 358659, 359041, 360179, 360286])
result = (numbers[:-1] + numbers[1:]) / numbers[1:] 
result
>>>
array([2.00045649, 1.98091347, 1.15934334, 1.99849499, 1.99824871,
       1.99755832, 1.94869415, 1.9975187 , 1.9991922 , 1.99796927,
       1.99953159, 1.99893605, 1.99684046, 1.99970301])
```

BTW, please use all lowercase and underscore (snake case) for variable names. This is more pythonic.

Comment: Thanks for the code I have another issue relating this question if you could take a look at it that would be great. Thanks : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65999759/using-multiple-functions-with-correlated-arrays-numpy-python?noredirect=1#comment116692000_65999759